How to get outllok calendar list?
I have set up a azure app and granted all required permission to get calendar list of logged in user
Now I am calling calendar list api from post man with all required credentials with the scope following Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadBasic
i am getting access token successfully
but using that token when i am calling calendar list api https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
i am getting following error
{"error":{"code":"AuthOMMissingRequiredPermissions","message":"The AadGuestPft token doesn't contain the permissions
required by the target API for calling app
'00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"a244c7b2-8c6f-4c98-874c-5f8e1df48d02","oAuthEventcV":"tEIoCwoZzcePn4FTJroLdw.1.1.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidGrant","requestId":"71f80207-9747-4191-928c-7180601269f5","date":"2024-12-16T14:22:18"}}}


Hi @jigneshAnsodariya, Are you logged in as a guest user in your tenant?

As Guest users don't have mailboxes within the resource tenant so you cannot fetch the Calendar data, Trying by changing endpoint query from /<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token to  /common/oauth2/v2.0/token or /organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token and generate the access token and use same access token to GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars and let me know this works for you or not

@PratikJadhav when i have used organizations same error, and when used common get error while authentication

ohh hello @PratikJadhav when i have changed both end points to  /common/oauth2/v2.0/token and /common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize then worked, Thanks a lot

@jigneshAnsordiya, Are you using authorization code flow? If yes, have you generated code using /common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? endpoints

Can I post as an answer? which helps community

Please check below answer


error:"code":"AuthOMMissingRequiredPermissions","message":"The AadGuestPft token doesn't contain the permissions
required by the target API for calling app

This error occurs usually, when a user is logged in as a guest user, As Guest users don't have Exchange Mailboxes within the resource tenant so you cannot able to fetch the Calendar data.
User are only able to fetch the Calendar events in the root tenant where user is created.
To resolve the error, need to generate access token using authorization_code flow,  For generating code use/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize endpoint and for generating access token /common/oauth2/v2.0/token.
Registered Multi-Tenant Microsoft Entra ID application in resource tenant, Added Calendar.ReadWrite Delegated type API permission and Granted Admin Consent like below:

Using authorization_code flow to generate the access token.
To get code, I ran below authorization request in browser:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=<AppID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=YOUR REDIRECT URI
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345


Now, generated access token using below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id = <app_id>
client_secret = <client_secret>
grant_type=authorization_code
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
code=<code>



To list the calendar events:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars


Reference:
Microsoft QnA Thread by CarlZhao-MSFT
